# Deployment issues on railway.app. Getting GLIBC not found error

Tags: python, discord, playwright-python

I have deployed a discord bot to a railway using playwright python. It's working smoothly on a local server but getting

```
/opt/virtualenvironment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/driver/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.36' not found (required by /nix/store/xpxln7rqi3pq4m0xpnawhxb2gs0mn1s0-gcc-12.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6)
```

this error on railway.app.
below is my build command

```
python -m venv /opt/virtualenvironment && . /opt/virtualenvironment/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt && playwright install
```

any help is appreciate.

I have tried on local server and it's running smoothly but getting the above error while deploying.